# TERR - Spotfire Custom Column Expression not working using stringdist

Tags: r, spotfire, stringdist, terr

This works fine in R Studio.

```
library(stringdist)
result <- afind(input1, input2, method="cosine")
distance <- result[2]
real_distance <- distance[[1]][1]
output <- real_distance
```

When I add it as a column expression in Spotfire, where input1 is a column and input 2 is a document property, I get a cryptic error message.

I am not sure if I can use external libraries in custom column R expressions in Spotfire, and am not sure what the issue is?

Error is:

> TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R returned an error (4)
>
> The expression function 'SearchDistance' could not be executed.
>
> Error in .Call() : dims [product 1290496000000] do not match the
> length of object [2005811200]
> eval(script, envir = .GlobalEnv)
> eval(script, envir = .GlobalEnv)
> withCallingHandlers({
> afind(input1, input2, method = "cosine")
> .Call()

****UPDATE*******

If I enable TERR debugging I get this:

Data function 'CalculateSearchScore' debug output (3)

Unmarshalling 2 input parameters.
Input 'input1', sent by inline XML
chr [1:1136000] "MYALGIA FEVER" "FATIGUE" "ASTHENIA" "CYSTITIS" ...

- attr(*, "SpotfireColumnMetaData")=List of 1
  .. $ Description: chr ""
  Input 'input2', sent by inline XML
  chr [1:1136000] "NAUSEA" "NAUSEA" "NAUSEA" "NAUSEA" ...
- attr(*, "SpotfireColumnMetaData")=List of 1
  .. $ Description: chr ""
  Done unmarshalling input parameters.
  Loading required package: stringdist

My column formula is as below:

```
SearchDistance([medical_term],"${MedicalTerm}")
```

I had assumed when you use this in a calculated column that it would run once per row, passing in each column value independently...perhaps what it is doing is passing in a vector containing the entire set of column values?

******SOLUTION***********

This works:

```
library(stringdist)

calculate_match_score <- function(target, pattern) {    
    print(target[1])
    result <- afind(target, pattern, method="cosine")
    distance <- result[2]
    return(distance[[1]][,1])
}

output <- calculate_match_score(target = input1, pattern = input2[1])
```

Comment: it works for me, both in RStudio (pointing to TERR) and in Spotfire. The only thing is that real_distance should return a column for an expression function, so I would remove the last [1].
I called with input1 the name of a column and input2 the document property value (surrounded by quotes)
You could try it as a data function (not expression function) and see if it works for you. If it does not, then maybe check your TERR version compatibility with stringdist.

Comment: what do you mean remove the last [1].  I need to return a single Real value, and this is how I do it, returning a list wont work as a column expression?  You cant use data functions as column expressions though, do you mean just to test TERR?   Also, does stringdist need to be on the TERR server, if I have installed locally and am using the client locally for now?  I did test a data function and it did return a table called output with a value in it.

Comment: @GaiaPaolini I updated the post with the TERR debug output, and how I have defined my custom column formula

Comment: Yes in expression functions you pass an entire column and return an entire column. That's why I asked if you could remove the [1]. In your example, you are sending a column of 1136000 values and the input2 is also vectorized to 1136000 values (all equal to NAUSEA).   Which seems fine.  My suggestion to use a data function was to rule out problems with TERR itself, rather than with the way the expression function is called.
My example works so I don't understand why yours does not, unfortunately.

Comment: mine is defined as function type=Column Function, return type=Real and category=Statistical Functions

Comment: @GaiaPaolini so what aFind returns if I send in 1000 items (1000 items in the data), is actually a 1000 x 1000 matrix, so not sure how yours is working.  It matches each column, against a vector of 1000 "NAUSEA" values, and so returns a 1000x1000 matrix of results

Comment: can you try input2=input2[1] before you call afind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246939/discussion-between-smackenzie-and-gaia-paolini).